# How can I change the colour of index and ToolTip in Canvasjs multi line chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, canvasjs

So I am working on my project that takes data and displays it on to chart I am new to JS and I never have used Canvasjs. I want to change the colour of the index and ToolTip as you can see in the below image I was able to change the line colour but it doesn't change the colour in the index and tooltip and when I Hover over a line it shows the previous colour on Marker. I hope I made it easy to understand.

What I want to change

[image: Requrements]

So here is my .js code

````
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    labelFontColor: '#f5f6fa',
    title:{
        text: ""
    },
    axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "DD MMM,YY",
        lineColor: "#f5f6fa",
        fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
        labelFontColor: "#f5f6fa",
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Temperature (in °C)",
        suffix: " °C",
        lineColor: "#f5f6fa",
        fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
        labelFontColor: "#f5f6fa",
    },
    legend:{
        cursor: "pointer",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontColor: "#f5f6fa",
        fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
    },
    toolTip:{
        shared: true
    },
    data: [{
        name: "Myrtle Beach",
        type: "line",
        markerSize: 0,
        lineColor: "#2196f3",
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,25), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,26), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,27), y: 29 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 31 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,29), y: 30 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,30), y: 29 }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Martha Vineyard",
        type: "line",
        markerSize: 0,
        lineColor: "#f44336",
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 20 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,25), y: 20 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,26), y: 25 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,27), y: 25 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 25 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,29), y: 25 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,30), y: 25 }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Nantucket",
        type: "line",
        markerSize: 0,
        lineColor: "#ffca28",
        showInLegend: true,
        yValueFormatString: "#0.## °C",
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [
            { x: new Date(2017,6,24), y: 22 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,25), y: 19 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,26), y: 23 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,27), y: 24 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,28), y: 24 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,29), y: 23 },
            { x: new Date(2017,6,30), y: 23 }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e){
    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else{
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}

}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this answer was so simple just replace

this:-

`lineColor`

to:-

`color`

If you want the same color to the line, Legend Marker and in ToolTip use `color`
instead of `lineColor`.

Because `lineColor` is only gonna change the color of the line in the chart.